# algebraic expressions in python

Tags: python, plot, algebra

I'm working with some relatively simple algebraic expressions in python and wondered if there's a better way of plotting algebraic expressions than what I'm currently doing:

I have the equation of a notch filter (below image - left side from a book; the right side graph is the fig generated by my code), and so far my code works though is crude.

**Is there a better way of plotting the magnitude? As shown the constants are; R = 50.0, C = 470e-12, L = 54e-6, and the desired frequency range is from 0 to 2MHz.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

R = 50.0
C = 470e-12
L = 54e-6

FREQ = []
DATA = []
for i in range(1, 200):
    f = i*10000.0
    w = 2*np.pi*f

    Ztop = w*L - 1.0/(w*C)
    Zbot = math.sqrt( (math.pow(R,2) + math.pow((w*L) -(1.0/(w*C)),2)) )
    Zout = abs(Ztop / Zbot)
    FREQ.append( f/1e6 )
    DATA.append( Zout )

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(FREQ,DATA, '-k')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
plt.ylabel('Mag.')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main improvement I'd suggest is using Numpy's array broadcasting facility. Basically this will perform a mathematical operation on a whole array at once. Other than that, there's nothing really *wrong* with your code, though you could calculate the entire magnitude in one expression. That's your call, depending on whether you think it makes the code clearer.

```
# creates 201 values evenly spaced from 0 to 2e6, inclusive
f = np.linspace(0, 2e6, 201)
w = 2 * np.pi * f
# now calculate the magnitude for all 201 values at once
magnitude = (w * L - 1 / (w * C)) / np.sqrt(R**2 + (w * L - 1 / (w * C))**2)
# now you can plot magnitude vs. frequency
plt.plot(f / 1e6, magnitude, '-k')
```

Comment: Thanks David, yes 'array broadcasting' is far better - I didn't know python/numpy could do this.

Comment: `(w*L - 1/(w*C))` could be factored out.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`sympy`](http://sympy.org/) to plot symbolic expressions:

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import pi, pprint, sqrt, symbols # $ pip install sympy
from sympy.plotting import plot

f = symbols("f")
L, C, R = symbols("L, C, R", real=True)
w = 2*pi*f
W = w * L - 1 / (w * C)
mag = abs(W / sqrt(R**2 + W**2))
pprint(mag)
plot(mag.subs({R: 50.0, C: 470e-12, L: 54e-6}), (f, 1, 2e6))
```

#### Output

```
│                    1           │
│       2⋅π⋅L⋅f - ───────        │
│                 2⋅π⋅C⋅f        │
│────────────────────────────────│
│     ___________________________│
│    ╱                         2 │
│   ╱   2   ⎛             1   ⎞  │
│  ╱   R  + ⎜2⋅π⋅L⋅f - ───────⎟  │
│╲╱         ⎝          2⋅π⋅C⋅f⎠  │
```

[image: magnitude]